# Dsum/Running Total using textbox and comboBox - Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox, sum, cumulative-sum

I am trying to calculate sales of agents seperately in the database. For total sales the DSUM is working fine. But if i try to bound it to some criteria (specific aget name) it gives ?NAME? error. Here is my code i applied for value selected from combobox.

```
=DSum("[totalsales]","MainTable","[Agent_Name]='" & me.cbo1 & "'")
```

and code for textbox is .

```
=DSum("[totalsales]","MainTable","[Agent_Name]='" & me.filteragent & "'")
```

here is the detail of the items on my form...

1: There is no Subform on the form
2: Form is based on MainTable
3: filteragent is unbounded textbox
4: cbo1 is a comboBox peresent on that form taking values from Agent_Name field on MainTable
5: Filter agent is Unbounded textbox on the form
6: agentwisesum is the name of unbounded textbox on which i am appling the dsum function

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ica.png)

kindly tell where i am doing wrong in the code. thanks

Comment: Does this eliminate the name error? `=DSum("[totalsales]","MainTable","[Agent_Name]='" & [filteragent] & "'")`

Comment: now the textbox keep bliking rapidly and if i type some criteria in filteragent textbox it show this  #Error

Comment: MainTable is sales data? Do you save the agent's name or is it really agent ID? If the field is a number type then you certainly aren't saving name. Don't use apostrophe delimiters for number type field. Can't use `Me.` qualifier in query or textbox expressions, only in VBA.